# Adding a React Component within dangerouslySetInnerHtml or similar

Tags: html, reactjs, string, parsing, components

I'm making a Gatsby site, and after running some GraphQL queries, I pass some HTML strings into React components. I've been able to render these with dangerouslySetInnerHtml, html-react-parser, etc. However, I'd like to also just write component tags within the original Markdown and render those as components.

A simple example of this would be

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const RedDiv = () => {
    return <div style={{ color: "red" }}>This is a red div</div>;
  };

  const StringRedDiv = "<div style={{color: 'red'}}>This is a red div</div>";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RedDiv />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: StringRedDiv }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-swanson-u5077?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Obviously, we don't need to use dangerouslySetInnerHtml here, but I'd like to achieve the desired effect (in this case having both divs have red text) using a method which takes an HTML string and transforms it into React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you can use the [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const html = "<div style={{color: 'red'}}>This is a red div</div>";
    return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>;
  }
}
```

On a side note, in order for the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or alternatively the `ReactHtmlParser` to work, you must use valid HTML attributes.

For instance, the style attribute in your example:

```html
<div style={{color: 'red'}}>This is a red div</div>
```

should be changed to:

```html
<div style="color: red;">This is a red div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Out of curiosity, I also tried it when passing the string `"<RedDiv/>"` and that doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to make that work as well?

Comment: I don't think that's possible though, as you need to pass valid HTML (not JSX) strings